# Stack columns with accompanying label column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statistics, kernel-density

I am try to stack a group of columns in order to fit a Kernel Density estimator to in order to understand how the probability of observing an interval changes with respect to a change in time and price.

My current DataFrame is as follows (not exact values, just an example):

```
date        price   1d_change  2d_price_change
2017-01-03  10.2    1.0        7.8
2017-01-04  11.2    7.8        9.4
2017-01-05  17.0    3.6        1.5
2017-01-06  20.6    -2.1       ...
2017-01-07  18.5    ...        ...
```

I would like to stack each price change column into one single column, and create another column that corresponds to the change in time, for example:

```
price_change    time_interval
10.2            1
11.2            1
17.0            1
20.6            1
18.5            1
7.8             2
9.4             2
1.5             2
```

I am aware that I can simply use pd.hstack() to achieve this, but I am unsure of how to create a corresponding column that labels the change in time.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up source data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'date': ['2017-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06'], 
'price': [10.2, 11.2, 17, 20.6], 
'1d': [1, 7.8, 3.6, -2.1], 
'2d': [7.8, 9.4, 1.5, 3.3]})

df = df[['date', 'price', '1d', '2d']]

print(df)
```

```
         date  price   1d   2d
0  2017-01-03   10.2  1.0  7.8
1  2017-01-04   11.2  7.8  9.4
2  2017-01-05   17.0  3.6  1.5
3  2017-01-06   20.6 -2.1  3.3
```

Now for the solution. The basic idea is as you mentioned to use `stack`. But some prep work is needed in terms of naming the axes properly, so that when we stack and `reset_index`, the column names are what we want. The final step is to simply replace columns name labels '1d', '2d' etc with the appropriate integer.

```
x = df.set_index('date').stack()
x.index.set_names(['date', 'time_interval'], inplace=True)
x.name = 'price_change'
print(x)
```

```
date        time_interval
2017-01-03  price            10.2
            1d                1.0
            2d                7.8
2017-01-04  price            11.2
            1d                7.8
            2d                9.4
2017-01-05  price            17.0
            1d                3.6
            2d                1.5
2017-01-06  price            20.6
            1d               -2.1
            2d                3.3
```

```
stacked = x.reset_index().replace({'price': 1, '1d': 2, '2d': 3})
print(stacked)
```

```
          date  time_interval  price_change
0   2017-01-03              1          10.2
1   2017-01-03              2           1.0
2   2017-01-03              3           7.8
3   2017-01-04              1          11.2
4   2017-01-04              2           7.8
5   2017-01-04              3           9.4
6   2017-01-05              1          17.0
7   2017-01-05              2           3.6
8   2017-01-05              3           1.5
9   2017-01-06              1          20.6
10  2017-01-06              2          -2.1
11  2017-01-06              3           3.3
```

Comment: That's great - thank you very much for such a prompt response and great solution!